# Check state of togglebutton android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-togglebutton

Im new to android and I don't get the code on the developers website about this really, I just want to check if the state of the toggle button is on or off. I have the following scenario

```
if (isCheckedToggleButton?)
{
    // do something         
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

And a method as the guide suggests

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view)
{
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton)view).isChecked();

    if(on) {
        return;
    } else {

    }
}
```

So I just want to see if the toggle button is on or off so I can decide whether to execute the code inside the if or the else. Unfortunately the method provided by the android guide is a void so it doesn't return a boolean. How can I still check the state?

```
        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lift"
            android:textOff="Uit"
            android:textOn="Aan"
            android:id="@+id/switchLift" android:layout_below="@id/btnEindpunt"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnEindpunt"/>
```

Comment: See here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this

```
myToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if(isChecked)
            // Do something
        else
           // Do the other thing
    }
});
```

Change

```
ToggleButton myToggleButton = ((ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.switchLift));
```

to

```
Switch myToggleButton = ((Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchLift));
```

Also change `isChecked` to something else like `mIsChecked` or inside the listener use `YourClassName.this.isChecked` for changing its value. There is already a local variable with same name.

Comment: It gives me a null pointer exception on the first line of your code. One line on top of that I have CompoundButton myToggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.switchLift);

Comment: Double check "switchLift" is the id of the ToggleButton in the current layout of the activity?

Comment: Thats because the code you have written above my code is wrong somehow. Does any Toggle button exist in the layout you are using with id `switchLift`? Please add more code where I can see how you are initalizing it

Comment: The first line of code comes from another layout. Thats because I have a layout where I fill in stuff and decide whether to turn options on or off with the toggle button and then I submit it and then I have to check if the toggle button is checked. The code is inside onCreate method of an activity.

Comment: Please add more code where you are using the code I have suggested.

Comment: I also added the xml file of the switch in the question.

Comment: First of all is the xml part you have posted is in layout file `mapview`?? Second you are using wrong statement to initialize the Switch. See my edit for this.